# Не могу создать виртуальную среду через venv

Tags: python, venv

Пробовал писать и в cmd, и в powershell — не создаётся папка.

Когда пишу команду `python -m venv venv`, он мне отвечает "Python" на следующей строчке и ничего не происходит.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Нужно удалить python установленный через магазин приложений windows, установить с официального сайта https://python.org

Comment: @insolor, спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ответ в соответствии с [комментарием автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495735/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-venv#comment2681647_1495735).

Необходимо удалить Python, который вы установили через магазин приложений Microsoft Store, и установить его с [официального сайта](https://python.org).

Comment: Вы если даете ответ в соответствии с чужим комментарием, помечайте этот ответ как общий. иначе очень некрасиво получается.

Comment: @strawdog, хорошо, буду знать на будущее — спасибо ;)

Comment: На будущее само-собой. надо сейчас отредактировать свой ответ и пометить как общий.

Comment: @strawdog я это уже сделал.